# Return records based on two values with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, given an array of values, I can select all records with an attribute with a value in that array:

```
trip_array = [31, 37, 40]
@flights = Flight.where(trip_id: trip_array)
```

This gives me a list of all flights where the trip_id is 31, 37, or 40.

However, I need to select on a pair of values. I was hoping to do something like so:

```
trip_sections_array = [[31, 1], [37, 2], [40, 1]]
@flights = Flight.where([:trip_id, :trip_section] => trip_section_array)
```

So I effectively want to return all flights where `(trip_id = 31 and trip_section = 1) or (trip_id = 37 and trip_section = 2) or (trip_id = 40 and trip_section = 1)`, but for any arbitrary two-dimensional array.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to resort to using string SQL conditions for this.  Something like:

```
trip_conditions = trip_sections_array.map { "(trip_id = ? AND trip_section = ?)" }.join(" OR ")
Flight.where(trip_conditions, *trip_sections_array.flatten)
```

For more information, see the rails guide on [pure string conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions)

Comment: That's what I was afraid I'd have to do. Regardless, it's working with your solution, so thank you.